# object does not contain a definition for 'Skip' Umbraco razor

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I'm trying to sort some nodes by their first letter, and page them in razor.(Umbraco). But get a "object does not contain a definition for 'Skip'" error when it hits the foreach.

```
pagesToList = homeNode.Children.OrderBy("Name");

IEnumerable<DynamicNode> nl = @homeNode.Children.Items;
pagesToList = nl.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(currentLetter));
```

This is what @pagesToList outputs:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNode]


foreach(dynamic item in pagesToList.Skip(1){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly using the wrong property. If you are only after those nodes just below your **homeNode**, then don't use the Items property. Also, try not to cast your objects. C# has an effective var object. Assuming that homeNode is a DynamicNode, then it might be worth trying the following:

```
pagesToList = homeNode.Children.OrderBy("Name").Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(currentLetter));
```

Then your code should work. Please note that again we are using var because we want the object declared at compile-time, instead of using dynamic, we should only really do when we are accessing some unknown, or *dynamic*, properties the pagesToList object):

```
foreach(var item in pagesToList.Skip(1)){

}
```

So to summarise, it looks like your code was using the property "Items", which gave us an array of DynamicNode[] instead of an IEnumerable object.

I hope this helps you out. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks however I get a "Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type" error when I use this.

Comment: Isn't the issue to do with that the .where statement brings back a dynamicnodelist, where as .StartsWith returns a generic list?